# Получить частоту звука и его громкость Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио

Необходимо получить звук с микрофона, выводя его частоту и громкость в данный момент.

Есть пример на чистом С#   https://habrahabr.ru/post/247385/   , но не для Unity. У него же свой ввод.

Код для C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Rainbow
{
//  Δ∂ωπ
public static class Filters
{
    public const double SinglePi = Math.PI;
    public const double DoublePi = 2*Math.PI;

    public static Dictionary<double, double> GetJoinedSpectrum(
        IList<Complex> spectrum0, IList<Complex> spectrum1,
        double shiftsPerFrame, double sampleRate)
    {
        var frameSize = spectrum0.Count;
        var frameTime = frameSize/sampleRate;
        var shiftTime = frameTime/shiftsPerFrame;
        var binToFrequancy = sampleRate/frameSize;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<double, double>();

        for (var bin = 0; bin < frameSize; bin++)
        {
            var omegaExpected = DoublePi*(bin*binToFrequancy); // ω=2πf
            var omegaActual = (spectrum1[bin].Phase - spectrum0[bin].Phase)/shiftTime; // ω=∂φ/∂t
            var omegaDelta = Align(omegaActual - omegaExpected, DoublePi); // Δω=(∂ω + π)%2π - π
            var binDelta = omegaDelta/(DoublePi*binToFrequancy);
            var frequancyActual = (bin + binDelta)*binToFrequancy;
            var magnitude = spectrum1[bin].Magnitude + spectrum0[bin].Magnitude;
            dictionary.Add(frequancyActual, magnitude*(0.5 + Math.Abs(binDelta)));
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    public static double Align(double angle, double period)
    {
        var qpd = (int) (angle/period);
        if (qpd >= 0) qpd += qpd & 1;
        else qpd -= qpd & 1;
        angle -= period*qpd;
        return angle;
    }
}
}
```

И применение этого в чистом C#

```
     var spectrum0 = Butterfly.DecimationInTime(frame0, true);
                    var spectrum1 = Butterfly.DecimationInTime(frame1, true);
                    for (var i = 0; i < frameSize; i++)
                    {
                        spectrum0[i] /= frameSize;
                        spectrum1[i] /= frameSize;
                    }

                    var spectrum = Filters.GetJoinedSpectrum(spectrum0, spectrum1, ShiftsPerFrame, Device.SampleRate);
```

Как применить это в Unity?

Ответ на решение многоуважаемого Kit Scribe
Вероятно, данное решение как то перегружает память. Приложение крашиться сразу же. Это всё что я понял из длинного лога Android Monitor.
Может вам будет виднее.

```
  04-14 11:40:50.406 358-358/? W/AudFlgTh: Using by PID 22814, 
 ProcessName:com.Cogpany.Producgame  
04-14 11:40:50.486 22814-22834/? I/Unity: 44100min

                                      (Filename: 
  ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
    04-14 11:40:50.486 22814-22834/? I/Unity: 44100max

                                      (Filename: 
  ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
 04-14 11:40:50.486 22814-22834/? E/libc: mmap fail (pid 22814, tid 22834, 
size -405344256, flags 0x22, errno 12(Out of memory))
 04-14 11:40:50.486 22814-22834/? E/libc: mmap fail (pid 22814, tid 22834, 
  size -405344256, flags 0x22, errno 12(Out of memory))
  04-14 11:40:50.486 22814-22834/? E/Unity: Could not allocate memory: 
  System out of memory!
                                      Trying to allocate: 3889620040B with 
  16 alignment. MemoryLabel: FMODSample
                                      Allocation happend at: Line:154 in 
                                      Memory overview

                                      [ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 5603046B | 
  peak: 7933847B | reserved: 5755046B 
                                      [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B 
| reserved: 262144B 
                                      [ ALLOC_GAMEOBJECT ] used: 87498B | 
 peak: 90921B | reserved: 93141B 
                                      [ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 93698B | peak: 
 377641B | reserved: 94515B 
                                      [ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 0B | peak: 0B 
    |    reserved: 0B 
                                      [ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 32768B | 
    peak: 0B | reserved: 2719744B 


                                      (Filename:  Line: 996)
     04-14 11:40:50.496 22814-22834/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 
   0x00005c8c (code=1), thread 22834 (UnityMain)
    04-14 11:40:50.556 355-355/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 
    'htc/htc_europe/htc_a3qhdul:4.4.2/KOT49H/362779.4:user/release-keys'
     04-14 11:40:50.556 355-355/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
   04-14 11:40:50.556 355-355/? I/DEBUG: pid: 22814, tid: 22834, name: 
   UnityMain  >>> com.Cogpany.Producgame <<<
   04-14 11:40:50.556 355-355/? I/DEBUG: debuggerd: checkTellHTCSettings
    04-14 11:40:50.556 355-355/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 
      (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00005c8c
    04-14 11:40:50.556 999-1266/? V/HtcNativeCrashUtil: Read id1=-1243796867 
 id2=-217320719, they are start flags. This is HTC header
  04-14 11:40:50.896 358-857/? V/SRS_Proc: ParamSet string: beats_icon=off
   04-14 11:40:50.896 358-857/? V/SRS_Proc: ParamSet string: audio_start=OFF
   04-14 11:40:50.896 999-999/? V/AudioService: Receive 
   BEATS_NATIVE_NOTIFICATION from Native AudioTrack!!! notificationOn=false
 04-14 11:40:50.896 999-999/? V/AudioService: Receive 
 BEATS_NATIVE_NOTIFICATION from Native AudioTrack!!! notificationOn=false
  04-14 11:40:50.896 999-1163/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: Headset UEVENT: 
  {SUBSYSTEM=switch, SWITCH_STATE=0, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/switch/Beats, 
  SEQNUM=46687, ACTION=change, SWITCH_NAME=Beats}
    04-14 11:40:50.896 999-1163/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: Beats UEVENT: 
 STATE:0
  04-14 11:40:50.896 999-1163/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: Beats UEVENT: 
  bests_status:false
   04-14 11:40:50.896 339-523/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): 
   Parameter 'CDROM_TYPE' not found
    04-14 11:40:50.896 339-523/? W/Vold: Ignoring unknown switch 'Beats'
    04-14 11:40:50.896 999-1163/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: Headset UEVENT: 
   {SUBSYSTEM=switch, SWITCH_STATE=0, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/switch/Beats, 
    SEQNUM=46687, ACTION=change, SWITCH_NAME=Beats}
  04-14 11:40:50.896 999-1163/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: Beats UEVENT: 
 STATE:0
  04-14 11:40:50.896 999-1163/? V/WiredAccessoryManager: Beats UEVENT: 
    bests_status:false
    [anon:libc_malloc]
  ***ОЧЕНЬ много дебагов с указанием адресов памяти. Вырезал, а то вообще 
   читать невозможно.
   E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: com.Cogpany.Producgame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Вопрос решился с помощью [этого варианта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443851/unity3d-check-microphone-input-volume) с англоязычной версии Stackoverflow.

Вы можете инициализировать класс, чтобы работать с ним. Я не совсем понял что там в скрипте за что отвечает (слишком технически оформлены комментарии), но в Unity встроить его можно так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Filters
{
    public const double SinglePi = Math.PI;
    public const double DoublePi = 2 * Math.PI;

    public static Dictionary<double, double> GetJoinedSpectrum(
        IList<Complex> spectrum0, IList<Complex> spectrum1,
        double shiftsPerFrame, double sampleRate)
    {
        var frameSize = spectrum0.Count;
        var frameTime = frameSize / sampleRate;
        var shiftTime = frameTime / shiftsPerFrame;
        var binToFrequancy = sampleRate / frameSize;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<double, double>();

        for (var bin = 0; bin < frameSize; bin++)
        {
            var omegaExpected = DoublePi * (bin * binToFrequancy); // ω = 2πf
            var omegaActual = (spectrum1[bin].Phase - spectrum0[bin].Phase)/shiftTime; // ω=∂φ/∂t
            var omegaDelta = Align(omegaActual - omegaExpected, DoublePi); // Δω=(∂ω + π)%2π - π
            var binDelta = omegaDelta/(DoublePi*binToFrequancy);
            var frequancyActual = (bin + binDelta)*binToFrequancy;
            var magnitude = spectrum1[bin].Magnitude + spectrum0[bin].Magnitude;
            dictionary.Add(frequancyActual, magnitude*(0.5 + Math.Abs(binDelta)));
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    public static double Align(double angle, double period)
    {
        var qpd = (int) (angle / period);
        if (qpd >= 0) qpd += qpd & 1;
        else qpd -= qpd & 1;
        angle -= period * qpd;
        return angle;
    }
}

public class Micro : MonoBehaviour // скрипт под названием Micro
{
    filter = new Filters() // инициализируем класс Filters
}
```

Также я бы на вашем месте посмотрел в сторону [Microphone Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html). Возможно некоторые полезные методы вы для себя возьмёте оттуда.

И вот ещё переписанный и слегка упрощённый пример с англоязычной версии [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443851/unity3d-check-microphone-input-volume):

```
public class MicInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float micLoudness;
    string device;
    bool isInitialized;
    AudioClip clipRecord = new AudioClip();
    int sampleWindow = 128;


    //Инициализация микрофона
    void InitMic()
    {
        if(device == null) device = Microphone.devices[0];
        min_cap, max_cap = Microphone.GetDeviceCaps(device);
        clipRecord = Microphone.Start(device, true, min_cap, max_cap);
    }


    // Окончание записи
    void StopMicrophone()
    {
        Microphone.End(device);
    }


    // Преобразовываем данные в audioclip
    float LevelMax()
    {
        float levelMax = 0;
        float[] waveData = new float[sampleWindow];
        int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (sampleWindow + 1); // при указывании null мы возьмём первый микрофон
        if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
        clipRecord.GetData(waveData, micPosition);

        // Получаем пик на последних 128 образцах
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleWindow; i++)
        {
            float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
            if (levelMax < wavePeak) levelMax = wavePeak;
        }

        return levelMax; // возвращаем пик
    }


    void Start()
    {
        InitMic();
        isInitialized = true;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        // levelMax равен наивысшей нормализованной мощности 2, значение маленькое, потому что < 1 (комментарий мной не очень понят, поэтому ниже оригинал)
        // levelMax equals to the highest normalized value power 2, a small number because < 1
        // Задаём возвращённое значение LevelMax() глобальной переменной, чтобы мы могли работать с данными
        micLoudness = LevelMax();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Ваше решение крашит приложение. Посмотрите пожалуйста лог в тексте вопроса, а то он не влазит в комментариии.

Comment: @Dmitrii посмотрел, жуть. А какая у вас, вообще, цель? Для чего вам нужно отлавливать input микрофона?

Comment: 1)Да просто получить громкость звука, желательно в децибеллах, но это уже нюансы. 
2)Получить частоту звука в данный конкретный момент, в Герцах желательно.

Comment: @Dmitrii ну, это сложно. У меня, к сожалению, такого опыта не было. А что крашится? Пример с англоязычного Stackoverflow?

Comment: Нет, ваш второй пример. Мы почти сделали получение громкости, не сдавайтесь) Что может вызывать краш?

Comment: @Dmitrii честно, я понятия не имею. Я не очень силён в понимании того, что такое звук и как его надо ловить и замерять. Если крашится второй вариант, почему не попробовать первый? Вы же сами его предложили, но просто не знали, как засунуть в Unity

Comment: Решение от английского SO сработало!
Кажется ваше упрощение что то сломало)

Comment: @Dmitrii да, вполне возможно) Хотя я думал, что просто убрал оттуда лишнее типа `OnEnable()`, `OnDisable()`, заменив нормальными функциями) Рад, что вопрос разрешился!