# unity, как определить громкость звука в игре или звука в реальной жизни

Tags: unity3d, аудио

можно-ли привязать float переменную к громкости звука из микрофона в реальной жизни или же к громкости аудио клипа в unity, что-бы если сказать тихо переменная была равна 10 а если громко то 100, срочно

Comment: Сдесь конвертирование децибел в 0-100 (можно и в 10-100) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470596/how-to-set-a-sliders-volume-from-the-audio-mixerss-volume-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

Звук с микрофона уже находили в [Получить частоту звука и его громкость Unity C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651696/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-unity-c), а присвоить параметром volume (подробнее https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html).